# I am trying to get my friend name and ids with graph api v2.4, but data returns empty:

Tags: ios, swift, fb-graph, fbsdk

hi i am trying to fetch Facebook friend list who using my app when i try this function i getting empty data

my sample code

```
let request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")

    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Friends are : \(result)")
        } else {
            print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
        }
    }
```

and my output is

```
FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me/friends should  contain an explicit "fields" parameter
ID is: 964865453559288
2015-12-21 18:25:55.635[12226:218972] fb_id 964865453559288
Friends are : {
data =     (
);
}
```

Comment: use  "me/taggable_friends" instead of "me/friends"

Comment: i tried but not working bro

Comment: then Please use latest version of sdk and use taggable friends

Comment: bro ham using latest version only

Comment: then it should work  . .my code is working fine

Comment: let me give my code to you

Comment: Thanx for an Advance

Comment: this is for objective c

Comment: I haven't hands on swift so please convert code

Answer (score 0):

USE user_id to fetch friends.It is working fine . Try it

```
-(void)fetchFriendList:(NSString*)userid
{

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/taggable_friends",userid];

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:string
                                  parameters:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {

    ///// your results
    }];




}
```

Comment: Baiscally I am passing user id

Comment: there is something changed in FBSDk not getting any data